# how to configure two different cname pointing to same load balancer?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, load-balancing, cname-record

I have a load balancer setup in aws.
the instance is has `nginx` and `uwsgi` with `django`
This works perfectly with a using a `subdomain.example.com` with `CNAME` pointing to the load balancer.

I have a static page with another instance (`static.example.com)`, which I figure it's just a static page, no point spinning an instance just for it so I want to combine the static page into the load balancer.  I kind pretty much finished all the configuration on the server side.  One last step is change the `dns` then I figured, it says the `CNAME` already existed that I cannot create another `CNAME`.

Is not possible?

EDIT (Rephrase with more details)

In aws, I have setup a load balancer which has a target group with two instances in there. which is currently using `nginx, uwsgi and django` With the load balancer, aws gives its own DNS name (`loadb-10434632.us-we.elb.amazonaws.com (A Record)`)
So in my own DNS I have to setup a `CNAME` saying `subdomain.example.com` points to `loadb-10434632.us-we.elb.amazonaws.com` This part works fine.

I have a single `ec2 instance` running which is now `static.example.com` the DNS for this one is with `A record` pointing `static` to `23.23.23.43` which then `static.example.com` works properly.

Now I am thinking of moving the single `ec2 instance` static file into the `two instances of the load balancer`  I did the moving, I configured what are needed in `site-available` so the last step for me was to go to my DNS setting and create another `CNAME` pointing to `loadb-10434632.us-we.elb.amazonaws.com`  Which is where `godaddy` gives me the error saying record already existed. P.S. I already removed the original `A record` before creating the `CNAME`

Comment: Question is ambiguous, please edit it to be more precise. The CNAME for the static page is likely on a different domain, I don't see why it can't be created. Nginx can listen to as many domains as you like.

Comment: It's a big ambiguous, but it sounds like you are looking for name-based virtual hosting in nginx which is very doable and nginx should be able to serve a static page for a different domain without hitting uwsgi/django.

Comment: Make sure you don’t have any existing A or CNAME records for static.example.com.

Comment: @Appleoddity ya I am sure the CNAME did not exist.

Comment: @Tim I tried to rephrase with more details, hopefully it's easier to understand.  As you mentioned, nginx can listen to as many domains, so I am not really understanding why `godaddy` gives this error

Comment: Not just CNAME records. A records too. You can’t have both. Mae sure there are no matching A records with this name.

Comment: @Appleoddity yup I made sure there's no records matching at all :(

Comment: Well, this may seem obvious, but GoDaddy has pretty good technical support. Give them a call.